# tslint not excluding node_modules in angular project

Tags: angular, typescript, tslint

I tried to perform the following to exclude `node_modules` from `tslint`.
But none of them resolved the issue.

I am confused if it is because of the way I call the `node_modules` folder.

**First attempt** - Added the following in `tsconfig.json` and `tsconfig-aot.json`

```
"exclude": [
    "../node_modules/**/*",
    "./node_modules/**/*",
    "node_modules",
    "node_modules/**/*.ts",
    "**/node_modules/**/*",
    "**/node_modules/**"
]
```

**Second attempt** - Added `exclude` to each project section in `.angular-cli.json`

```
"lint": [{
        "project": "../../../tsconfig.json",
        "exclude": "./node_modules/*" // also tried **/node_modules/**/*
    },
    {
        "project": "../../../tsconfig-aot.json",
        "exclude": "./node_modules/*"
    }
],
```

**Third attempt** - Executed `tslint-cli` with `--exclude` option

```
tslint --exclude node_modules --project tsconfig-aot.json
tslint --exclude node_modules --project tsconfig.json
```

Still no change. Whenever I do `yarn webpack:build`, I am still getting these warnings from node_modules.

Also in `tsconfig.json` and `tsconfig-aot.json`, it already has `"skipLibCheck": true`

**UPDATE**

I installed the npm module `angular-select2-component` which was causing the error. Added the tslint stacktrace.

```
WARNING in ./node_modules/angular-select2-component/index.ts
[1, 41]: file should end with a newline

 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/home/home.module.ts 13:34-70
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/app.main.ts

WARNING in ./node_modules/angular-select2-component/src/select2.component.ts
[22, 24]: Type boolean trivially inferred from a boolean literal, remove type annotation
[43, 22]: missing whitespace
[44, 40]: missing whitespace
[46, 14]: missing whitespace
[54, 45]: missing whitespace
[67, 14]: missing whitespace
[61, 32]: missing whitespace
[79, 18]: missing whitespace
[59, 51]: " should be '
[54, 33]: == should be ===
[35, 45]: missing whitespace
[44, 11]: missing whitespace
[54, 11]: missing whitespace
[61, 15]: missing whitespace
[30, 1]: Consecutive blank lines are forbidden
[13, 15]: The selector of the component "Select2Component" should be named kebab-case and include dash (https://angular.io/styleguide#style-05-02)

 @ ./node_modules/angular-select2-component/index.ts 6:9-43
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/home/home.module.ts
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/app.main.ts

WARNING in ./node_modules/angular-select2-component/src/custom-input.ts
[59, 2]: file should end with a newline
[20, 47]: missing whitespace

 @ ./node_modules/angular-select2-component/src/select2.component.ts 25:21-46
 @ ./node_modules/angular-select2-component/index.ts
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/home/home.module.ts
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/app.main.ts
```

Comment: Could you give us the stack trace of your linting please ?

Answer (score 9):

## Solution one:

Try to specify explicitly from which directory should start checking. On my end it is:

```
"scripts": {
    "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
},
```

This solution works only if your project is well structured ie:

```
package.json
some-other.conf.js
src/here_is_app_code
```

## Solution two:

```
{
    "extends": [
      "tslint:recommended"
    ],
    "linterOptions": {
        "exclude": [
            "node_modules"
        ]
    }
}
```

More information can be found in [this PR](https://github.com/palantir/tslint/pull/2409)

## Solution three:

```
tslint \"./**/*.ts\" -e \"node_modules\"
```

`-e` is an abbreviation for `--exclude`, introduced with [this PR](https://github.com/palantir/tslint/pull/1006).

Comment: Could you please add some explanations to solutions 2 and 3?

Comment: Find out more info in the links provided in the edited answer.

Comment: And...? Still have problem with tslint?

Comment: Hi .. I had tried all the solutions, but surprisingly none worked. I ditched the node_module which caused the issue and took a different module.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is not your tsconfig.  In fact, it should exclude `node_modules` by default.  The problem is the `angular-select2-component` module.  It is not built correctly.

Most typescript modules are built such that there is a `main` in the `package.json` which points to a JS file (the compiled output of the project).  They also have a `types` entry in `package.json` which points to the root type definitions file `.d.ts`.

The module you are importing (`angular-select2-component`) has its `main` entry set to `index.ts`, a TypeScript file.  It has no `types` entry.  This is not entirely unsupported, it "can work".  Typescript will basically treat this module as a second source folder.  This means that when you are compiling your project it is also compiling `angular-select2-component`.  It won't matter if you exclude it from `tsconfig.json` because it has to be compiled.  This would be the same result you would get if you tried to exclude one of your source files but it was imported by another source file.  This is also why `skipLibCheck` is ignored.

So there is no way to exclude `angular-select2-component` from compilation because it is needed.  You might be able to use @nickolay's solution which excludes it from linting but leaves it in for compilation.  Notice that his implementation of "solution 3" uses globs and it doesn't look like you were using globs in  your attempt at "solution 3".

Comment: Also, it appears this lack of packaging is an open issue (https://github.com/godbasin/angular-select2/issues/32) but it has been for over a year so :shrug:

Answer (score 0):

Also flag `--type-check` for tslint can produce errors from `node_modules` just remove flag `--type-check` when you ran command

For example

```
tslint -e \"node_modules/**/*.ts\" -p tsconfig.json -c tslint.json
```

instead of

```
tslint -e \"node_modules/**/*.ts\" -p tsconfig.json -c tslint.json --type-check
```